Can there be a program similar to the space shuttle program?
The Space Shuttle program was mankind's first reusable spacecraft program. Later on July 21st, 2011, it was discontinued due to maintenance expenses. Is it possible (Given today's technological advancements) to recontinue a similar program using a similar concept? (In which the body of an aircraft and spacecraft is combined). I believe it could help explore planets with atmospheres and make them cheaper to explore. If it's not possible, why not?

Other planets mostly don't have runways.

Also, see Dream Chaser, X-37, and whatever China’s spaceplane is called.

what would have changed about reality to make it not possible now?

@fyrepenguin Term appears to be the rather imaginative "Reusable Experimental Spacecraft"

Would it be possible? Yes; all the material science, aerospace engineering, etc. of the 1970 exists today.
Should it be done? Probably not; instead of a generalist spacecraft which can do most things sort of OK, a specialized launch vehicle, specialized interplanetary transport, and specialized lander would be better. Spaceplanes are best used within atmospheres — outside atmospheres their aerodynamic surfaces, heat shields, and landing gear are dead weight — and vehicles optimized for space-to-space transport can't enter atmospheres due to a lack of those features but have higher performance due to not having to carry around a useless set of wings. Such a set of vehicles would arguably be more expensive to develop, sure, but also arguably cheaper over longer periods due to not being three separate systems crammed into one trenchcoat
A cheap and effective enough spaceplane would be useful for launching the parts for constructing the interplanetary transport and the lander but wouldn't be useful outside that. In that regard there are several proposals and one prototype for fully-reusable launch vehicles, which, unlike the Space Shuttle, wouldn't need to replace parts jettisoned during launch. The Space Shuttle was groundbreaking technology when it was made but today there'd better ways to implement the "space truck" concept.
